# Docker stack deploy doesn't start services or deploy correctly

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have this compose file

```yaml
version: "3.3" 

volumes:
  jenkins_home: 
    external: false
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/var/jenkins_home'
  certs:
    external: false
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: 'bind'
      device: '/etc/certs'

services:
  docker:
    image: docker:dind 
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - certs:/certs/client
    ports:
      - "2376:2376"
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: /certs
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
  
  jenkins:
    image: git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/jenkins
    build: 
      context: services/jenkins
      args:
        ssl_pass: changeit
    restart: unless-stopped 
    depends_on:
      - "docker"
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - certs:/certs/client
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "3268:3268"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
 
  icecc-scheduler:
    image: git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/icecc-scheduler
    build: services/icecc-scheduler 
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  icecc-daemon:
    image: git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/icecc-daemon
    build: services/icecc-daemon    
    restart: unless-stopped
    network_mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
```

when I run `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml build_farm`
It claims to start everything successfully. But running `docker stack services build_farm` I get

```
ID             NAME                         MODE         REPLICAS   IMAGE                                                                    PORTS
tap0zlw086wm   build_farm_docker            replicated   0/1        docker:dind                                                              *:2376->2376/tcp
n13pcmy8zpip   build_farm_icecc-daemon      global       0/1        git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/icecc-daemon:latest      
ofpsosrhrzoq   build_farm_icecc-scheduler   replicated   0/1        git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/icecc-scheduler:latest   
b9llhoe97vwz   build_farm_jenkins           replicated   0/1        git.example.com:8444/devops/docker-services/jenkins:latest           *:3268->3268/tcp, *:8080->8080/tcp, *:8443->8443/tcp, *:50000->50000/tcp
```

Which seems to mean none of the services actually started, I can't access any of them which seems to confirm this.

The second issue is that the icecc-daemon container only has one replica despite being started in `global` mode with 2 nodes on the swarm
`docker node ls`

```
ID                            HOSTNAME   STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
rc6aajdnwnis4dvn4um7qcwk9     ex12873    Ready     Active                          20.10.12
phnvvy2139wft9innou0uermq *   ex12874    Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.12
```